# Unable to intall libboost

Tags: apt, package-management

I get the following:

```
myPrompt: ~ $ sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
Reading package lists ... finished
Dependency tree
Status information is read ... finished
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that
You have requested an impossible situation or if the
Are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have
not created or have not left Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libboost-all-dev: Depends: libboost-date-time-dev but it is not installable
                    Depends: libboost-python-dev but it is not installable
                    Depends: libboost-thread-dev but it is not installable
E: Problems can not be corrected, you have held broken packages back.
```

<sub>Translated from german</sub>

I have no clue why this is. Tried to fix this according to some stuff found on the web... Like `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: try to install it via `aptitude install libboost-all-dev`

Comment: I'm not sure if this applies, try `apt-get build-dep`

Comment: Also: try to do `sudo apt-get update` before installing new packages

Comment: @arsaKasra nope, it doesn't. Please type `man apt-get` to check what `build-dep` does.

Comment: @HanyAlsamman aptitude isn't installed by default in Ubuntu.

Comment: @Braiam I didn't get it then, I get it now, thanks for telling. I'm not sure if I should delete that, maybe that would be useful as a _it won't help_.

Comment: @Braiam Sure , but it is helpful

Answer (score 1):

You have unmet dependencies. Try to use `sudo apt-get install -f libboost-all-dev` to install unmet dependencies as well.